# Get numbers characters from a string

Tags: swift, swift3

How to get numbers characters from a string? I don't want to convert  in `Int`.

```
var string = "string_1"
var string2 = "string_20_certified"
```

My result have to be formatted like this:

```
newString = "1"
newString2 = "20"
```

Comment: Do you mean "number characters"?

Comment: What result do you expect for the string "a_1_b_2_3_c34"?

Comment: What about "৯" (BENGALI DIGIT NINE) or "" (MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT ONE) ?

Comment: @MartinR i expect 12334

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Pattern matching a `String`'s unicode scalars against Western Arabic Numerals

You could pattern match the `unicodeScalars` view of a `String` to a given `UnicodeScalar` pattern (covering e.g. [Western Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals)).

```
extension String {
    var westernArabicNumeralsOnly: String {
        let pattern = UnicodeScalar("0")..."9"
        return String(unicodeScalars
            .flatMap { pattern ~= $0 ? Character($0) : nil })
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let str1 = "string_1"
let str2 = "string_20_certified"
let str3 = "a_1_b_2_3_c34"

let newStr1 = str1.westernArabicNumeralsOnly
let newStr2 = str2.westernArabicNumeralsOnly
let newStr3 = str3.westernArabicNumeralsOnly

print(newStr1) // 1
print(newStr2) // 20
print(newStr3) // 12334
```

---

#### Extending to matching any of several given patterns

The unicode scalar pattern matching approach above is particularly useful extending it to matching any of a several given patterns, e.g. patterns describing different variations of [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals):

```
extension String {   
    var easternArabicNumeralsOnly: String {
        let patterns = [UnicodeScalar("\u{0660}")..."\u{0669}", // Eastern Arabic
                                       "\u{06F0}"..."\u{06F9}"] // Perso-Arabic variant 
        return String(unicodeScalars
            .flatMap { uc in patterns.contains{ $0 ~= uc } ? Character(uc) : nil })
    }
}
```

This could be used in practice e.g. if writing an Emoji filter, as ranges of unicode scalars that cover emojis can readily be added to the `patterns` array in the Eastern Arabic example above.

---

#### Why use the `UnicodeScalar` patterns approach over `Character` ones?

A `Character` in Swift contains of an extended grapheme cluster, which is made up of one *or more* Unicode scalar values. This means that `Character` instances in Swift does not have a fixed size in the memory, which means random access to a character within a collection of sequentially (/contiguously) stored character will not be available at O(1), but rather, O(n).

Unicode scalars in Swift, on the other hand, are stored in fixed sized UTF-32 code units, which *should* allow O(1) random access. Now, I'm not entirely sure if this is a fact, or a reason for what follows: but a fact is that if benchmarking the methods above vs equivalent method using the `CharacterView` (`.characters` property) for some test `String` instances, its very apparent that the `UnicodeScalar` approach is faster than the `Character` approach; naive testing showed a factor 10-25 difference in execution times, steadily growing for growing `String` size.

***Knowing the limitations of working with Unicode scalars vs Characters in Swift***

Now, there are drawbacks using the `UnicodeScalar` approach, however; namely when working with characters that cannot represented by a single unicode scalar, but where one of its unicode scalars are contained in the pattern to which we want to match.

E.g., consider a string holding the four *characters* `"Café"`. The last character, `"é"`, is represented by two unicode scalars, `"e"` and `"\u{301}"`. If we were to implement pattern matching against, say, `UnicodeScalar("a")...e`, the filtering method as applied above would allow one of the two unicode scalars to pass.

```
extension String {
    var onlyLowercaseLettersAthroughE: String {
        let patterns = [UnicodeScalar("1")..."e"]
        return String(unicodeScalars
            .flatMap { uc in patterns.contains{ $0 ~= uc } ? Character(uc) : nil })
    }
}

let str = "Cafe\u{301}"
print(str)                               // Café
print(str.onlyLowercaseLettersAthroughE) // Cae
                                         /* possibly we'd want "Ca" or "Caé"
                                            as result here                   */
```

In the particular use case queried by from the OP in this Q&A, the above is not an issue, but depending on the use case, it will sometimes be more appropriate to work with `Character` pattern matching over `UnicodeScalar`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the feedback! I'll need to take this in a moment :) The main reason I chose `UnicodeScalar` over `Character` in this use case is the better performance of the prior, as unic. scalars have a fixed size in the memory (as compared to the character extended grapheme cluster, which does not). In light of this, I'm uncertain if using `reduce` here might possibly affect performance negatively. Also, when using several patterns (`easternArabic...` example), I believe the `reduce` solution above will not conserve the intermutual ordering between letters from two different patterns.

Comment: so basiclly, if i have to work on string with unique unicodeScalar (like 1 2 3...9) it ll be faster to use unicodeScalar ? And If i've to work on string where characters can have more than 1 unicodeScalar like (è é ...) Character still better ?

Comment: @Mayke since you only want to filter out digits (`1` .... `9`), you wont run into an issue even if the string you are filtering on contains characters with containing more than 1 unicode scalar (è é ...) since these will still be excluded in the filtering (wont match your digits pattern). The possible issue arises when your pattern to match against contains unicode scalars which may be part of characters that are made up of more than 1 unicode scalar. E.g. if you'd like to pattern match against pattern `"a"..."m"`, then the unicode scalar approach might be fragile as a _character_ `é` ...

Comment: ... will partly pass the filter pattern matching, letting the `e` uniocode scalar part of `é` pass through the filter. Again, for your case (just digits), it should be safe to use the faster unicode scalar approach, but if you want to pattern match against patterns that contains unicode scalars which are a part of special 2-unicode scalar characters, then using the slower pattern matching against `Character` patterns might be a more sensible approach (refer to the Café example above).

Answer (score 17):

**Edit: Updated for Swift 4 & 5**

Here's a straightforward method that doesn't require *Foundation*:

```
let newstring = string.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }
```

or borrowing from @dfri's idea to make it a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    var numbers: String {
        return filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }
    }
}

print("3 little pigs".numbers) // "3"
print("1, 2, and 3".numbers)   // "123"
```

Comment: Note that you may omit `self` in the extension, making it even slighty more neat :)

Comment: why not also `return String(characters.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 })`

Comment: **Swift 5** extension String {
    var numbers: String {
        return String(self.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 })
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @uplearnedu.com.  In fact, its even simpler now because `String()` isn't needed and I left off `self.` as I had done before.  See update.

Comment: For Swift 5 - let newstring = string.filter { $0.isNumber }

Comment: @NilanshuJaiswal, that could be effective as well.  Note that it will match other Unicode characters that are numbers but not 0 to 9 (for example `"\u{215A}"`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Yeah, isNumber is not strictly confined to 0 to 9. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
import Foundation

let string = "a_1_b_2_3_c34"    
let result = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
12334
```

Comment: You can use simply `.joined()` instead of `.joined(separator: "")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift 2 example:

```
let str = "Hello 1, World 62"
let intString = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet
        .decimalDigitCharacterSet()
        .invertedSet)
    .joinWithSeparator("") // Return a string with all the numbers
```

Comment: Good, but the question is tagged "swift3", you may want to add a Swift 3 version. :)

Comment: This one isn't working ? I can't test this right now ...

Comment: Yes it works, but it's in Swift 2. OP needs a Swift 3 version, the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

For example with regular expression

```
let text = "string_20_certified"

let pattern = "\\d+"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count)) {
    let newString = (text as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
    print(newString)
}
```

If there are multiple occurrences of the pattern use `matches(in..`

```
let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))
for match in matches {
    let newString = (text as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
    print(newString)
}
```

Comment: I think you should get the length for your NSRange casting the string to NSString `(text as NSString).length` or getting the utf16 count `text.utf16.count`

Answer (score 0):

This method iterate through the string characters and appends the numbers to a new string:

```
class func getNumberFrom(string: String) -> String {
    var number: String = ""
    for var c : Character in string.characters {
        if let n: Int = Int(String(c)) {
            if n >= Int("0")! && n < Int("9")! {
                number.append(c)
            }
        }
    }
    return number
}
```